# Создать программно объект SKSpriteNode

Tags: xcode, swift, spritekit

Доброго времени суток !
Делаю игру, и объекты для нее создал через конструктор!
Но потом озадачился тем, что при создании новых уровней, было бы удобнее создавать объекты SKSpriteNode программно !
Честно говоря, пролазил много видеоуроков и форумов, и никак не могу найти нужную информацию. Где код не сходится, где вообще не тот материал.
Не могли бы помочь с данной задачей. Хотелось бы создать программно около 20 SKSpriteNode
([image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пример итога того, что должен получится в изображении)